# django: how to pass condition to .is_valid() without populating all serializers parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

From the frontend, it was necessary to get the question object in order to understand what to return in the get function from the frontend, a request is sent to the post function With the id of the object to be returned.

With class TestQuestionList
in the post function I don't need to create a new object, so I don't fill in the fields, image, answers in the request, but django requires me to fill in these fields and returns - bad request 400
`"POST /api/questions/ HTTP/1.1" 400 85`

views.py:

```
class TestQuestionList(APIView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.questions = [1]
    def get(self, request):
        romms = TestQuestionBlok.objects.filter(id__in=self.questions)
        serializer = TestQuestionSerializers(romms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer1 = TestQuestionSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer1.is_valid() :
            self.questions = serializer1.data['questions']
            return Response(serializer1.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer1.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py:

```
class TestQuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TestQuestionBlok
        fields = ('__all__')
```

models.py:

```
class TestQuestionBlok(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='questionsImages/')
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(TestAnswers)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

How can I bypass these requirements?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why would you use a post request if you are not aiming for the creation/update of an object? In addition, I do not see a `mail` function - "...with class TestQuestionList in the mail function ...".

Comment: @antpngl92 From the frontend, it was necessary to get the question object in order to understand what to return in the get function from the frontend, a request is sent to the post function With the id of the object to be returned

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using a "POST" request to return some object to the FE? If that is the case, you should use a "GET" request for data fetching not "POST".

Comment: @antpngl92 No, you misunderstood me, so that the get function knows which object to return, frontend makes a post request in which the object ID is passed

Comment: You pass object ID to the GET request in the query params, not through the POST request. So your get request URL would look something like this `domain/api/resource/<int:resource_id>/`. Once you hit the get function, it receives a resource_id as a function parameter which ID you use to query the required object. You do not need POST for selecting objects!

Comment: @antpngl92 But there is more than one ID, I need a list with id like [1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API should look like this in order to get several objects:

```py
class YourAPI(APIView):
    class InputSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        ...

        objects = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            queryset=YourResourceModel.objects.all(),
            required=False,
            allow_empty=True,
            allow_null=True
        )

        ...
    class OutputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = TestQuestionBlok
            fields = ('__all__')
    
    def post(self, request):
        serialzier = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.validated_data)
```

The serializers do not have to be part of your API it is just an example. However, it is a good practice according to some style guides.

Check out [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Essentially, your FE passes the PKs of the objects that you need as an array to the BE in a variable called `objects`, you can call it whatever you want.